# How to make auto-request in python on the website

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, python-requests, gis

I need to get data from [this](https://uldk.gugik.gov.pl) website.

It is possible to request information about parcels by help of a URL pattern, e.g. https://uldk.gugik.gov.pl/?request=GetParcelById&id=260403_4.0001.186/2.

The result for this example will look like this:

> 0
>   0103000020840800000100000005000000CBB2062D8C6F224110297D382512144128979BC870702241200E9D7C57161441CFC255973F702241C05EAADB7D161441C7AF26C2606F2241A0AD0EFB67121441CBB2062D8C6F224110297D3825121441

This is wkb format with information about geometry of the parcel.

The problem is:
I have excel spreadsheet with hundreds of parcels id. How can I get each id from the Excel file, make request as described at the begining and write result to file (for example to Excel)?

Comment: You can read `.xls` files in Python using [xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. After that, just write a loop to go over every ID and make an http request. Finally, to write data to an `.xls` file, you can use [xlwt](http://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

Comment: Thanks for instruction. Do I need for http request any libray as well?

Comment: Yes. Use the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to read the Excel file and process the parcel ids.

For each of the parcel id you can access the url and extract the required information. Following code does this job for the given URL:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://uldk.gugik.gov.pl/?request=GetParcelById&id=260403_4.0001.186/2')
result = str(r.content, 'utf-8').split()
# ['0', '0103000020840800000100000005000000CBB2062D8C6F224110297D382512144128979BC870702241200E9D7C57161441CFC255973F702241C05EAADB7D161441C7AF26C2606F2241A0AD0EFB67121441CBB2062D8C6F224110297D3825121441']
```

As you have several hundreds of those ids, i'd write a function to do exectly this job:

```
import requests

def get_parcel_info(parcel_id):
    url = f'https://uldk.gugik.gov.pl/?request=GetParcelById&id={parcel_id}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    return str(r.content, 'utf-8').split()

get_parcel_info('260403_4.0001.186/2')
# ['0', '0103000020840800000100000005000000CBB2062D8C6F224110297D382512144128979BC870702241200E9D7C57161441CFC255973F702241C05EAADB7D161441C7AF26C2606F2241A0AD0EFB67121441CBB2062D8C6F224110297D3825121441']
```